# What's the Excel equivalent of Stata's collapse(sum) command?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Stata, I'd type collapse(sum) x, by(y z)

(where x,y,z = variable names).
What should I type in Excel to get the same result?

Edit: for those unfamiliar with Stata, this will "collapse" the observations in the dataset by all possible intersections of groups. 
E.g. x = # of pens bought, y = occupation, z = state. Each observation in the dataset records a sale, and the occupation and state of the buyer. This command will collapse the dataset to show only how many pens in total were bought by lawyers in FL, how many pens were bought by lawyers in TX, how many by accountants in AZ etc (for every intersection of state and occupation).

Comment: For those of us who don't use Strata, can you explain what this does?

Comment: @anon, I understand this formula of yours will sum column **x** grouped by columns **y and z**. If that's so, you could achieve the same result in Excel with something like this: `=SE(E(Y1=Y2;Z1=Z2);"";SOMASE(Z:Z;Z1;X:X))` my excel is in portuguese so the functions were translated. In English it should look like this:  `=IF(AND(Y1=Y2,Z1=Z2),"",SUMIF(Z:Z,Z1,X:X))`, but I can't test to be shure.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1069894/anon) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1069896/anon). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you posted the question and then registered with a new account.  You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, it must be done under the user account that created it.  Attempting the edit as "another user" puts it into a review queue, where a number of users with sufficient rep must agree that the edit is consistent with what the original author intended (and reviewers tend to err on the side of caution).  Having a second account will also interfere with commenting within your thread and accepting an answer.

Comment: I switched from MS Office some years ago, so can't vouch for sure about recent versions, but I'm not aware of Excel having a similar built-in, single-function solution.  You can do it with a pivot table (fast and simple but not dynamic), or a complex formula (the component functions needed to do it exist, but you need to figure out from scratch how to build the formula).  Are you just asking about Excel equivalency, or are you looking for an actual solution of one type or the other?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a pivot table for the same purpose as Stata's "collapse". So if your Stata command was "collapse (sum) Pop Jobs, by(year)", then your pivot table would have "year" in the rows. I would do "jobs" and "pop" one at a time as the "value" and set "value field settings" for "sum". Or you could put them both in the value field at the same time. It wouldn't need anything in the columns, unless you wanted to further parse out the field you are collapsing by some other field.

Comment: The question asks about “collapse(sum) x, by(y z)”, but your answer talks about “collapse (sum) x y, by(z)” (not quite the same).   It’s generally best to answer the question *as asked.*